# Testing with Jest and Enzyme - dive is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Tried to replicate the `dive()` example from enzyme but continue to get `TypeError: wrapper.find(...).dive is not a function`

**Code:**

```
class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="in-bar" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Bar />
      </div>
    );
  }


it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
  expect(wrapper.find('.in-bar').length).toBe(0);
  expect(wrapper.find(Bar).length).toBe(1);
  expect(wrapper.find(Bar).dive().find('.in-bar').length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Are you using a version of Enzyme >= 2.5.0? https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#250-october-17-2016

Comment: i was using 2.4.7!!! you are the mvp!!

Answer (score 0):

`.dive()` was added in enzyme v2.5.0:

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#250-october-17-2016